# Ajax request and text/xml

Tags: ajax, firefox, xmldocument

I am requesting and xml file over ajax, the server uses the header text/xml for the data returned. Firefox reads this header and turns the data into an XMLDocument object which means I can't use it with jQuery. How can I get my XML document as plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xmlHttp` object returned has a responseXML property. This maps to an XmlDocument. If you read the `textContent` of the childnodes of this document, you will be able to retrieve the plain text response.

For instance:

```
// Works on FF. For IE, you can read the lastChild.text property.
var responseText = xmlHttp.responseXML.lastChild.textContent;
```

Alternatively, you can access the responseText property to get the entire response as a string:

```
// Works on both IE and FF.
var responseText = xmlHttp.responseText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by serializing:

```
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var text = serializer.serializeToString(xmldoc);
```